# Missing architecture when adding framework to AIR Native Extension (ANE)

Tags: ios, frameworks, air, adobe

Currently I'm working on a Native Extension for AIR. I already got it working perfectly for android and I'm now taking on iOS. So far I've got it running and I have every method do some basic things, like showing an alert message. So I know the ANE is building and working fine by itself.

But now the problem I'm facing. I try to add some frameworks. One I build myself and is working in native apps and some third party ones. The ANE is still building fine, but when I add it to a testproject and run it, it says it's ignoring my file for missing the right architecture.

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /var/folders/zn/r6p91gln37n2323yj8rw1q6c0000gp/T/0bd78fa0-1b71-   4371-a6c5-a4ad3073df62/libcom.mycompany.myproduct.a, missing required architecture armv7 in file /var/folders/zn/r6p91gln37n2323yj8rw1q6c0000gp/T/0bd78fa0-1b71-4371-a6c5-a4ad3073df62/libom.mycompany.myproduct.a (2 slices)
ld: file too small for architecture armv7 
Compilation failed while executing : ld64
```

I have them added in my platform options:

```
<platform xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/extension/3.8">
    <sdkVersion>6.0</sdkVersion>
    <linkerOptions>
        <option>-ios_version_min 6.0</option>
        <option>-framework coreTelephony</option>
        <option>-framework EventKit</option>
        <option>-framework MediaPlayer</option>
        <option>-framework MessageUI</option>
        <option>-framework SystemConfiguration</option>
        <option>-framework AdSupport</option>
    </linkerOptions>
    <packagedDependencies>
        <packagedDependency>ios/myproduct.framework</packagedDependency>
    </packagedDependencies>
</platform>
```

And I package it int the build command.

```
adt -package -target ane myproduct.ane extension.xml -swc myproduct.swc -platform Android-ARM -C android . -platform iPhone-ARM -platformoptions iosoptions.xml ios/myproduct.framework -C ios  . -platform default -C default .;
```

So can someone explain why it is correctly building the ane, but it cannot be run? And perhaps you can put me on the right track to solve this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have figured it out. I was pointed in the wrong direction. It was the ANE itself that caused the problem. It was not properly build for armv7, the build target for the native library was set to the simulator. I changed it to iOS device and it worked. Of course I'm going to make it compile for both the simulator and real devices soon.

If anyone stumbles upon this problem, feel free to send me a message and perhaps I can help.

Comment: i would like to know , where exactly have you changed to build target is it in Xcode in Build Settings ? or when you are building the ANE , user adt command ? i checked in my library "Build settings" in XCode it is done , "iOs Deployment Target" is Ios 4.3

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot check it because I no longer work for that company. I do recall though, the problem being that it was set for ARMv7 and not for i386. I believe it was in XCode build settings, but where exactly I do not know. Wishing you good luck, I wish I could hve been more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

It's from the Xcode Menu (on the right of the build button), you choose iOS device instead of the iOS simulator and then press the build button.